# A 4ª edição do livro JavaScript: O Guia Definitivo ainda é uma fonte confiável?

Tags: javascript

Eu recebi há pouco tempo o livro JavaScript O Guia Definitivo 4ª edição, que abrange a versão 1.5. Queria saber se ainda é valido para aprender o *core* da linguagem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Essa edição](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000486.do) deve estar bastante defasada (digo "deve" porque não li). Ela é baseada na versão 3 do standard da linguagem ([ECMAScript 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), sendo que "JavaScript 1.5" é isso mais algumas extensões exclusivas da Mozilla).

A edição é de 2001, e muita coisa mudou desde então. Em 2009, foi publicado o [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf), revisto em 2011 como [ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/). Essas edições são compatíveis retroativamente com a 3, mas aprender JS hoje baseado na versão 3 seria incentivar maus hábitos que estão caindo em desuso. Hoje em dia, eu recomendaria fortemente procurar uma versão do livro que seja baseada em ES6 (também chamado de ECMA-2015), ou pelo menos ES 5.1.

Olhando o índice da quarta edição, os capítulos 2 a 10 tratam do *core* da linguagem. Boa parte dos tópicos ali abordados se aplica ainda hoje, mas se você for se basear neles para aprender a linguagem, é bom considerar algumas mudanças introduzidas pelo ES5 (e ainda válidas em ES6):

- Novos métodos de arrays (em *Array.prototype*)
- Novas possibilidades para se trabalhar com herança via `Object.create`. Mudança de abordagem em relação às possibilidades de OOP da linguagem (sintaticamente não houve grande mudança, mas as práticas mudaram nesse período)
- ES5 garante mais compatibilidade entre browsers que a versão anterior da especificação. Por isso, diversos tópicos sobre compatibilidade no livro devem estar defasados.
- Entre outras, esta lista não é exaustiva.

Nos capítulos seguintes, que tratam das APIs implementadas nos browsers (principalmente as do DOM), houve mudanças ainda maiores de 2001 para cá. Se entendi bem, a quarta edição do livro não chega nem a lidar com Ajax.

---

PS: Ainda mais com as tags que você usou originalmente na pergunta. Em 2001, jQuery e AngularJS nem existiam!

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendo que vá para um livro que abrange recursos mais sólidos, dicas e truques. Assim você poderá implementar pensando em produção e crescimento contínuo. Se você tiver dúvidas sobre o mais básico a internet já possui muito material a respeito. Começando assim por algo mais consolidado você pode em seguida partir para usar recursos mais robustos como node.js, angular.js, meteor.js e etc.

Eu recomendo que comece por este livro, ele é muito bom e muitos desenvolvedores JS utilizam como manual. versão em português para compra:

http://www.novatec.com.br/livros/ninja-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Sim, tenho o livro e ele foi excepcional para meu aprendizado do JavaScript. O livro (como o autor mesmo diz nas primeiras páginas) é direcionado principalmente para o público que nunca teve nenhum contato com a linguagem, ele aborda tópicos simples de programação e vai avançando a cada capitulo até os níveis avançados (não muito avançados assim).

Infelizmente, ou felizmente para mim, o JavaScript está mudando para o ECMAScript 6, isso implicada que todos os livros atuais não serão completos mais. Muitas funcionalidades interessantes do ECMAScript 6 não são nem citadas nos livros atuais, por isso o que você deve ter em mente é: - quer aprender o JavaScript agora (do jeito que ele está) e depois se atualizar com as novidades ou esperar mais um pouco e já estudar o assunto da atualidade?

Se quer novidade pode começar lendo o seguinte livro https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read ele está sendo escrito e por isso sempre é atualizado com as novidades.

Comment: Você leu a quarta edição mesmo, ou uma mais recente?

Comment: O meu é a quinta edição, não deve ter tanto de diferente assim.

Comment: @RenatoTavares se saiu uma nova edição deve fazer toda a diferença.

Comment: É, parece que houve mesmo bastante mudança da quarta para a quinta edição: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101992.do